# why is my ubuntu 14.04 32 bit fresh install painfully slow on my fitpc2

Tags: software-installation, ssd, 32-bit, window, format

I have 14.04 64 on another machine running well on another machine.
I installed 14.04 32 bit on this Fitpc2 mini pc with an intel 40 gig ssd drive because it has 1 gig of ram.

I erased the SSD drive with HDDerase prior to the fresh install, it had been running windows XP formerly.

I installed ubuntu from a usb drive. I was never prompted to reformat the drive in any way after secure erasing it, nor upon installing the ubunu OS. Have just updated the ubuntu, that did not help.

The PC has an atom 1.6 processor, though an older machine, i figured ubuntu would run very well, especially with the SSD drive.
 I may have made a mistake in erasing/not formatting correctly the drive? I will try the intel firmware update for the hard drive.

Anybody have any clues?

A  couple of errors poat at startup. but its quick and hard to read them, I'll try and capture them.

Comment: Please tell my your GPU and did you install normal Ubuntu from Ubuntu.com

Comment: because you only have 1GB of RAM!

Answer (score 1):

you should use this http://lubuntu.net/ or this http://xubuntu.org/ as you only just meet the minimum system requierments for Ubuntu Unity.

You have 1GB of RAM the minimum for Unity 3d, also I think you have a integrated GPU, they suck.

As you can see you barely scrape past the minimum specs, that is why it is slow.

The minimum spec is what you need to install and the reccommended spec (twice your PC) is what you need for a good expiriance.

Also this would work on you PC [Linux mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/), again this may run slow though, there are many distros out there with lower spec than Unity.

Comment: I see, I thought (assumed) I was well above minimum for the 32 bit version. I'll explore the lighter versions. I bet it is indeed the integrated gpu....I'm running a memory test, so can't list it for a bit. Very helpful, didn't check out the min req's thoroughly when I began what has become an arduous process.

Comment: Yes Unity is a GPU heavy desktop (with the same resource cost as windows 7), but your 1 GB of RAM is the main issue, the system alone will use almost this, so programs will struggle to get some, the light distros are designed, for exactly this, also if you are on a desktop you could try just getting a new RAM stick they are cheap these days.